# CMake problem when building video driver for Intel AlderLake-S GT1

Tags: drivers, intel, cmake

I am trying to get a video driver to support my CPU supported video output (specifically the Intel AlderLake-S GT1).

Here is the output from inxi

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel AlderLake-S GT1 driver: N/A
```

The instructions I was following for the Intel media-driver on GitHub at https://github.com/intel/media-driver instruct me to build gmmlib at https://github.com/intel/gmmlib) which I have.

Unfortunately I cannot get the media-driver's cmake to find the build I did when I created gmmlib.

The "cmake ../media-driver" command complains with:

```
-- Checking for module 'igdgmm>=12.0.0'
--   No package 'igdgmm' found
```

I have the file structure as follows

```
./gmmlib
./media-driver
./build_media
```

I'm running the cmake command from within the "build_media" directory using the following.

```
cmake ../media-driver
```

When cmake is looking for a module, where does it look? What file is it looking for?  How do you direct it to a specific directory?

---

`uname -srm`: Linux 5.13.0-30-generic x86_64

```
lspci -k | grep -iE "VGA|video|3d|graphic" -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation AlderLake-S GT1 (rev 0c) 
DeviceName: Onboard - Video Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd AlderLake-S GT1 
Kernel modules: i915 
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 467d (rev 01)
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is your Linux kernel version? Do you use HWE stack for kernel and Xorg? What do you have for `lspci -k | grep -iE "VGA|video|3d|graphic" -A3 ` ?

Comment: Kernal version (per uname -srm): Linux 5.13.0-30-generic x86_64

Comment: Not sure about the HWE stack.  I didn't do anything specific so probably not.

Comment: Here's the output of the lspci command: "00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation AlderLake-S GT1 (rev 0c)
 DeviceName: Onboard - Video
 Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd AlderLake-S GT1
 Kernel modules: i915
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 467d (rev 01)
"

Comment: According to https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=6c4ff21b02 you have to get newest possible linux kernel for this Ubuntu version. Or upgrade whole system to 22.04 LTS with its 5.15 kernel and test possible progress here.

Answer (score 1):

[Search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=igdgmm) gives the following installation command:

```
sudo apt-get install libigdgmm-dev
```

and then you have to retry compilation.

Comment: Unfortunately the package available in libigdgmm-dev is 11.3.0 and the media-driver I pulled down from GItHub requires 12.0.

Comment: Here's what I was able to get to work.  I did a "sudo make install" in the libgmm project (12.0 version), even though the instructions in the README didn't have me doing that.  That put a "igdgmm.pc" file in the /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig directory.  That let cmake see the correct location.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help me with my display screen size.  It is stuck at 1024x768 (even though the monitor should handle much higher resolution).   I had assumed that I needed to update the driver but I guess I was going down the wrong path.  I'll ask a new question about how to debug monitor type not being discovered.